# Proof that a non-negative quadratic equation has at most one solution without using calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I'm working through Lax and Terrell's 'Calculus with Applications'. One of the first exercises is to work through the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (without calculus). I'm all good for my proof except for the first part: i.e., how do I prove that a non-negative quadratic equation has at most one solution?

I can 'explain' this geometrically, i.e., a non-negative quadratic equation can only have a solution where the vertex touches the X axis. However, this doesn't feel very 'rigorous'.

Is there a better, algebraic, proof I could use here?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use continuity?

Comment: Just for clarity, could you please type out the exact equation you're interested in? It is so much easier to talk about it if we have a concrete expression as common ground.

Comment: What "kind of" quadratic equation are we talking about here? After all $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ is also quadratic

Comment: Sorry, the function is defined as the polynomial p(x)=Px^2+2Qx+R

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(x):= ax^2 + bx + c \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and that there exist $x_1,x_2, x_1 \ne x_2$ s.t. $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = 0$. Then, by polynomial long division, $f(x) = (x-x_1)q(x) + r(x)$ where $r(x)$ has degree $0$ and $q(x)$ has degree $1$. But then $0= 0f(x_1) = 0q(x) + r(x_1) = r(x_1)$. So $r(x_1) = 0$, but $r(x) = d$ for some $d \in \mathbb{R}$ (since it has degree $0$), so $d = 0$. Thus $f(x) = (x-x_1)q(x)$. Then $q(x) = ux-v$ for some $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$. Also $0=f(x_2)= (x_2 - x_1)q(x_2)$. Then $x_2 - x_1 \ne 0$, by assumption, so $q(x_2) = 0$. Thus $ux_2 - v= 0$, or $v = ux_2$. But then
$$f(x) = (x-x_1)(ux+v) = ux^2 +(v-ux_1)x -x_1v = ax^2 + bx+c,$$
so $u=a$, so  $v= ax_2$. Thus, putting it together,
$$f(x) = (x-x_1)(ax-ax_2) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2).$$
Now let $x_3$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ (we can without loss of generality suppose $x_1 <x_2$, so $x_1 < x_3 < x_2$). Then $x_3 - x_1 > 0$ and $x_3 - x_2 <0$, so $k:= (x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)<0$. Thus
$$f(x_3) = a(x_3 -x_1)(x_3-x_2) = ak$$
so $f(x_3)$ has the opposite sign of $a$ (since $k$ is strictly negative). Then by assumption, for all $x$, $f(x) \geq 0$, so $f(x_3)\geq 0$. Thus $a \leq 0$. Then let $x_4 >x_1, x_2$. Then $x_4-x_1, x_4 - x_2>0$, so $k' := (x_4-x_1)(x_4-x_2) >0$. So
$$f(x_4) = a(x_4-x_1)(x_4 -x_2) = ak'.$$
Then $a \leq 0$ and $k' \geq 0$, so $f(x_4) \leq 0$. But also, by assumption $f(x_4) \geq 0$. Thus $f(x_4) =0$. But $k' \ne 0$, so $a = 0$.

Thus
$$f(x) = bx +c,$$
but it is easy to see that this is nonnegative for all $x$ iff $b =0$. Thus $f(x) = c$, but $f(x_1) =0$, so $0 = f(x_1) = c$, so $f(x) = 0$. But we assumed that $f$ has only two roots, but $f(x) = 0$ has infinitely many roots, so we have a contradiction. Thus a nonnegative quadratic cannot have two roots. But any quadratic also has at most two roots, so a nonnegative quadratic has at most one root.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $Ax^2+Bx+C\ge 0$ for all $x,$ with $A\ne 0.$

1. Take $x_0\ne 0$ where $|x_0|$ is large enough that $|B/Ax_0|<1/2$ and $|C/Ax_0^2|<1/2.$ Then $1+B/Ax_0+C/Ax_0^2\ge 1-|B/Ax_0|-|C/Ax_0^2|>0.$ Therefore $0\le Ax_0^2+Bx_0+C= Ax_0^2(1+B/Ax_0 +C/Ax_0^2)\implies Ax_0^2\ge 0\implies$ $\implies A\ge 0\implies A>0.$
2. Let $x_1=-B/2A$. Then $0\le Ax_1^2+Bx_1+C=A(x_1+B/2A)^2 +(4AC-B^2)/4A=(4AC-B^2)/4A,$ and since $A>0,$ therefore $0\le 4AC-B^2.$
3. The Quadratic Formula:   $Ax^2+Bx+C =0\iff x=\frac {-B\pm \sqrt {B^2-4AC}}{2A}.$ But $B^2-4AC\le 0 $ so $\sqrt {B^2-4AC} \not\in \Bbb R$ unless $B^2-4AC=0.$ So IF there exists $x_2$ with $Ax_2^2+Bx_2+C= 0$ THEN $B^2-4AC=0$ and $x_2=\frac {-B\pm \sqrt {B^2-4AC}}{2A}=\frac {-B\pm \sqrt {0}}{2A}=\frac {-B}{2A}.$

BTW. By the methods of 1., if $p$ is a non-zero polynomial and $p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ then deg($p$) is even and the leading co-efficient of $p$ is positive.